# ¿Qué significa el símbolo de más (+) en esta función?

Tags: javascript

Estaba intentando generar una fecha aleatoria dadas dos fechas (mínimo y máximo), y buscando por este foro, me encontré [la siguiente solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31379050/13207652) (la he simplificado pues no necesito tener en cuenta las horas):

```js
function randomDate(start, end) {
  return new Date(+start + Math.random() * (end - start));
}
```

No logro entender qué significa `+start`. ¿Por qué está el símbolo más (+) delante? He visto que sin él, no funciona.

Sí entiendo el funcionamento de la función, hice algo muy similar para encontrar números aleatorios, pero no entiendo qué significa el más.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: El simbolo + se utiliza en javascript para que te devuelva un numero, es una abreviatura de Number. Seguramente te devuelve el resultado en string y por eso te hace falta

Comment: No es una abreviatura de `Number`, @jbort. Es similar, pero no es lo mismo. [Aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLrgj.png) podéis ver una tabla con todas las maneras de convertir *cosas* a números. Por cierto, en inglés al símbolo + usado así se le llama unary plus (más unario??). Es una manera muy rápida y bastante fiable de convertir *cosas* a números. Y de hecho, en cuanto a optimización no se queda corto, siendo más rápido que otras maneras como `Number(x)` o `parseInt(x)`. Puede comprobarse en [jsbench](https://jsben.ch/NnBKM)

Comment: Dije que era una abreviatura porque realiza la misma funcion que Number, no por otra razón, espero que se entienda de esa manera. De todas formas, gracias por tu aclaración.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por sus buenas explicaciones. Ahora entiendo qué significa, y me ha parecido muy interesante revisar su rendimiento. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es una Manera poco elegante (Trampa de Programador) de decirle en tu caso que el "start" es de tipo numérico, pero OJO, no controla el error, que quiero decir con esto, que si le pasa una letra el programa se detiene con un error fatal `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`.

La manera correcta es utilizar la función "parseInt()" la conviertes a numérico.

Aquí unos ejemplos y ve que te devuelve:

```
console.log(parseInt("123"));  
console.log(parseInt("-123")); 
console.log(parseInt("100.50"));
```

Para validar (capturar el error) puedes hacer la comprobación que el resultado de aplicar la función "parseInt()" te devuelva como resultado "NaN", prueba con esto:

```
console.log(parseInt("abc"));
```

...y si quieres ver el error fatal ve el resultado de esto:

```
    <script>
        function sumarUno(start) {
            return +start + 1;
        }

        console.log(sumarUno(abc));
    </script>
```

Voy a editar mi respuesta por tu segundo comentario, si se puede capturar el error con un "try catch", en tu caso seria con este código:

```
 <script>
        function sumarUno(start) {
            return +start + 1;
        }
        try {
            sumarUno(abc)
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error("Aqui el error->" + error);
        }
        finally {
            console.warn("No se pudo sumar"); // siempre cierra el recurso
        }
    </script>
```

El try catch también maneja condicionales en el tipo de error que te serian muy útiles en todo el código en general y estos serian:

```
     <script>
        function sumarUno(start) {
            return +start + 1;
        }
        try {
            sumarUno(abc);  // Ejecutas la funcion
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof TypeError) {
                console.error("Si es por TypeError-> " + e);// sentencias para manejar excepciones TypeError
            } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
                console.error("Si es por RangeError-> " + e);// sentencias para manejar excepciones RangeError
            } else if (e instanceof EvalError) {
                console.error("Si es por EvalError-> " + e);// sentencias para manejar excepciones EvalError
            } else {
                // sentencias para manejar cualquier excepción no especificada
                console.error("Si no esta definida-> " + e); // pasa el objeto de la excepción al manejador de errores si lo tienes, sino lo mandas al console.log como esta en este ejemplo.
            }
        }
        finally {
            console.warn("No se pudo hacer la operacion"); // siempre cierra el recurso
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu amplia explicación. Solo una pregunta, ¿se podría hacer lo mismo usando el `+start` y capturando el error con un `try catch`? Saludos.

Comment: Estimado @Tupi edité la respuesta, para responder este comentario...

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, todo claro ahora. ¡Un saludo!